# Fastest way to "pass" a function to an other function

Tags: rust

I am wondering currently what is the fastest way to pass a function to another function. By that I don't mean necessarily to pass it as an argument. Also let us assume that I know before compile time which kind of concrete functions I want to use in the generic function.
The obvious way would probably be to pass it as an argument that implements one of the 3 closure traits, like the following:
`fn foo(i: i32, f: impl Fn(i32)->i32)->i32{ f(i) }`

With this approach I am not sure if f could for instance be inlined if I just pass a regular function. Am i correct if i think of the actual function passed as an instance of the type that is defined by its signature?

Another approach would be to define a dummy trait, that holds a function with the required signature:

```
trait dummy_trait{
    fn add(i:i32)->i32;
}

struct dummy_type{}

impl dummy_trait for dummy_type{
    fn add(i:i32)->i32{
        i+1
    }
}

fn add_outer<T:dummy_trait>(i: i32)->i32{
    T::add(i)
}
```

Then i could call it like this:
`add_outer::<dummy_type>(32);`
Like this i do not even have to pass the function as an argument. It should be able to for example inline here right? It just seems to be a little bit unwieldy, but i haven't found a better solution yet.

So my question is really if there is any performance difference between the two, and if so, if there is a nicer way to do the second option.

Comment: The best way to proceed is to measure the difference on the code you care about. You can also inspect the generated assembly on godbolt.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

```rust
trait dummy_trait{
    fn add(i:i32)->i32;
}

struct dummy_type{}
impl dummy_trait for dummy_type{ ...
```

This is *how function items (named functions) already work.* You don't need to define your own trait to get the advantage that this seems to provide. [Try this program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7711954a1cf2a58496372164a6e4eaf8):

```rust
fn add(x: i32) -> i32 { x + 1 }

fn foo<F: Fn(i32) -> i32>(i: i32, f: F) -> i32 {
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<F>());
    f(i)
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(foo(7, add));
}
```

It will print:

```
[src/main.rs:4] std::mem::size_of::<F>() = 0
[src/main.rs:9] foo(7, add) = 8
```

The size of `add` (as passed to `foo`) is 0 bytes, just like the size of `dummy_type` is 0 bytes. All the information about which code to execute by calling `f()` is provided at compile time by the function type `F`, not the value `f`.

(This is not true if you coerce `add` to a function *pointer* type, lowercase `fn(i32) -> i32` — then, there is an actual pointer being passed around and called. The optimizer still might eliminate the pointer since it is a constant, though.)

Answer (score 1):

> Am i correct if i think of the actual function passed as an instance of the type that is defined by its signature?

No. While there are a few differences, `fn(a: impl Trait)` is mostly equivalent to `fn<T: Trait>(a: T)`, so this call will be statically dispatched.

It's possible that if the function pointer goes through a ton of complex functions the compiler will miss the optimisation, but if you call e.g.

```rust
foo(5, add)
```

it's almost certain it'll inline the entire thing. You can easily test this behaviour on godbolt (the compiler explorer).

Comment: I checked it with godbolt(nice programm!) and it was indeed the same for both options. The only thing, that i can't quite wrap my head around is if actually any sort of function object is passed when using the first option. Intuitively it seems so, because a function is passed as an argument. However this not the case right? I am confused, because i can not do something like foo<add>(5), but have to give add as an argument. This is different to other type parameters, where i can just specify the type in front of the arguments, and then call an associated function in the function body.

Comment: @Foveng it's not really different, just that you're manipulating it by trait because it's more generic: you could write `fn(i32) -> i32` as a regular type but that would only allow actual static function pointers, not e.g. closures which capture their environment. Closures are the association of a function and an "environment", so they're structures, and each closure has its own (anonymous) type. By using `Fn`, the two are interchangeable.

Comment: @Foveng Well, it's `foo<type of add which doesn't have a name so you can't specify it here explicitly and it's inferred from the value parameter>(add, 5)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov in this case the type of `add` is `fn(i32) -> i32` as it's a static function, not a closure.